# Drupal save a node with required fields not complete

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a content type which has a lot of fields 50+. 30 or so are required fields. I want my user to be able so save the node before all the required fields have been filled in. The node can not be published until all the required fields have been filled in. Is there a way I can do this.

Comment: Can (or should) this data perhaps be split up into more than one node? You can always use a field to link to the sub-data. If it *must* be all contained within a single node instance, maybe you should look into writing a custom data-entry page which periodically saves in the background.

Comment: Yeah it needs to be 1 node sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. Required fields are exactly that. You'll need to make your fields optional and handle the node save event and prevent publishing until each of the fields has been filled in. If you don't feel like all that php, Rules module can handle this kind of thing very nicely - http://drupal.org/project/rules.

Another alternative is that you might be better off with something like a webform - http://drupal.org/project/webform, though I don't know if it has any save and resume functionality out of the box so you might need to check that out first.

Comment: Good call on the node save. That would work nicely. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

This module will do the job:

http://drupal.org/project/multistep

You can split your form to steps and only the fields in the current step have to be filled by the user.